# Catching juggernaut income message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, juggernaut

How to put the juggernaut push messages to show it in html in browser? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all documented here: https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut

Assume you have your Juggernaut server is setup and running and your app is publishing messages to Redis.

Let's assume you are publishing messages to `channel1`

Your html code should include the following javascript files (which come with Juggernaut):

```
<script src="/javascripts/json.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/socket_io.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/juggernaut.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And following that you should connect to the Juggernaut server and handle incoming messages

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  // Connect to Juggernaut
  var jug = new Juggernaut({secure: ('https:' == document.location.protocol)});

  // Log the fact we have connected
  jug.on("connect", function(){ log("Connected") });

  // Log disconnection
  jug.on("disconnect", function(){ log("Disconnected") });

  // Log reconnection
  jug.on("reconnect", function(){ log("Reconnecting") });

  jug.subscribe("channel1", function(data){
    // Your code to handle the incoming message
  });

  // Expose for debugging
  window.jug = jug;
</script>
```

Again a full end to end example is provided in the `README` on github